# Changing background after downloading the image-- best method?

Tags: javascript, css, image, download

I am making a weather app I want to change the background image depending on the weather. I am trying to get it to transition smoothly, but the problem I'm having is that the first time the image is downloaded, the transition (usually)  doesn't happen, presumably because the image takes longer to download than the actual effect change. For instance, if I get a city that is cloudy, the initial change is abrupt. But if I get another city that is cloudy after that, or go back to the same city, the cloudy image transitions smoothly.

The way I'm doing this is to say in javascript that if my response from the api tells me its cloudy, I set an attribute of the body to "cloudy" in javascript. In css, I have the background set to a cloudy image if the dataset is "cloudy." For instance:

```
 if(icon == "03d" || icon == "03n"){body.dataset.weather = "scattered-clouds"}
```

and then in css:

```
body[data-weather ="scattered-clouds"]::before{
    content: ' ';
    position: fixed; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: gray;
    background: url('img/clouds/pexels-chris-kane-166360.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    will-change: transform; 
    z-index: -1; 
    transition: 1.5s all ease;     
}
```

I could just download all the images up front, but this seems like bad practice and wasteful of data. Is there a more standard way of doing this?

Comment: *" I am trying to get it to transition smoothly"* ? Preloading all the images is not a good idea, yes. Now, it all depends on the effect you desire to achieve. My suggestion is to: Fade out the current weather image, load the new image and fade it in.

Comment: Sure, but that is the point of my question-- how do I load the new image first and fade it in?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Image() API [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image)

```js
    setTimeout(() => {
        const image = document.querySelector(".image");
        const img = new Image(); 
        img.onload = () => {
            image.src = img.src
            image.style.animation = "fadeIn 1s ease";
        };
        img.src = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1627156863760-f49b81d8ab77?fm=jpg&w=1950&fit=max';
    }, 2000);
```

```css
    @keyframes fadeIn {
        0% {
            opacity: 0;
        }

        100% {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
    .image-wrapper {
        width: 80vw;
        height: 80vh;
    }

    .image-wrapper img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
     }
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">
    <img class="image"
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534430480872-3498386e7856?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&fit=max&w=1950">
</div>
```